# Can't run tests with appium

Tags: macos, appium, codeception, appium-ios

The problem
Can't run tests!

- Appium version 1.8.1 / **command for run** `appium`

  - Environment
  - Appium version 1.8.1 / **command for run** `appium`
  - Node 10.6.0
  - ios_webkit_debug_proxy 1.8 / **command for run** `ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c my_udid:27753`
  - libimobiledevice v1.2.0
  - libplist v2.0.0
  - Real device : iPhone 6 (11.0)
  - MacOS 10.13.6

My logs
[Appium Server](https://gist.github.com/dmitrykorj/138e74b77e1bd99efa3f27aa0369a600)

Comment: There is bug in new node version. Please run `yarn -v` command and check yarn version.

Comment: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5477   https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5753 .  This might help you

Comment: have you created provisioning profile under your apple developer account with this device? also if you are running using safari, you have to set the developer settings under safari in the phone.